# Exception javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager

Tags: jpa, persistence, toplink

We've been working on this for days and we are stumped. This is supposed to be an easy tutortial using TopLink. We are trying to get this to work before we do our real web app. This is the following exception we get:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named pu1:
>   The following providers:
>   oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider
>   oracle.toplink.essentials.ejb.cmp3.EntityManagerFactoryProvider
>   Returned null to createEntityManagerFactory.
>           at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:154)
>           at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:83)
>           at client.Client.main(Client.java:45)
>   Java Result: 1

this happens after executing this line from our emf driver class:

```
emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pu1");
```

I'm assuming the problem is in our persistence.xml file (which is in the correct folder (WEB-INF/classes/META-INF). Also netbeans generated the xml file for us which is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence   
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="JPAExamplePU" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<jta-data-source>SomeDB</jta-data-source>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
<property name="toplink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

We were also thinking it may be an adding a library issue or something along that line. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: are you using OC4J app server?

Answer (score 3):

You have the wrong persistence unit name. Use the one from the xml (i.e. the one defined with `<persistence-unit name="..."`):

```
emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JPAExamplePU");
```

Comment: Ok we tried that, and so get the same error. We're thinking it has to do something with the filepath of the persistence.xml, but netbeans created the pu, so it should be in the correct spot right?

Comment: yes, it is in the correct place. Make sure your changes were deployed. ("the same error" would mean it's still looking for the wrong pu)